# Create Modal JDialog while things are processing

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, jdialog, jprogressbar

how do you create a Modal JDialog saying "loading" while a task is processing that shows after more than 3 seconds has passed?

Comment: It's pretty simple if the processing is happening in a thread separate from the UI thread. That is the preferable way to do it.

Otherwise you're dong the processing in your main UI thread and having to launch a separate UI thread just to work around your architecture.

Comment: yes the task is runing in a separate thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the task is to load an `InputStream`, see `ProgressMonitorInputStream`.

E.G. (untested)

```
ProgressMonitorInputStream pmis = new ProgressMonitorInputStream(
    parentComponent, message, inputStream);
ProgressMonitor pm = pmis.getProgressMonitor();
pm.setMillisToPopup(millisToPopup);
```

It will be necessary to load the `InputStream` in a `Thread` in order to avoid blocking the EDT.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on Paul's answer, a SwingWorker would work well for running your background task. You could then display either a progress or a progress monitor, and the tutorials can help you here: [How to Use Progress Bars](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html)

Comment: +1 Hover: I got a bit lazy with my answer and just demoted it to a comment.